# Joining multiple table in oracle 11g using sql query

Tags: oracle

i want all the column of treat_info table and corresponding fee of treatment table and equipment table.what is the sql query ?
The 3 tables image link is below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BFGC_k79UObHRjMGZpVXZwa3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use "LEFT JOIN" for not be sure if the fields are TREATMENT and EQUIPMENT are foreign keys.

So, you have the FEE value, if they exist.

```
select
T1.*
,T2.FEE as TREATMENT_FEE
,T3.FEE as EQUIP_FEE
from TREAT_INFO as T1
left join TREATMENT as T2 on T2.TREATMENT = T1.TREATMENT
left join EQUIPMENT as T3 on T3.EQUIPMENT = T1.EQUIPMENT
```